# How to implement a trait for iterators over implementors of that trait

Tags: rust

Say I have a trait, `Intersectable`, that is implemented for various geometric primitives. I wish to implement `Intersectable` for iterators over a list of these primitives.

I have the code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a6d1d06b06daeb0d887feb6b5c927632)):

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;

struct Ray {}
trait Intersectable {
    fn intersect(self, ray: &Ray) -> bool;
}

struct Circle {}
impl Intersectable for Circle {
    fn intersect(self, _ray: &Ray) -> bool {
        true
    }
}
impl Intersectable for &Circle {
    fn intersect(self, _ray: &Ray) -> bool {
        true
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Intersectable for T
    where T: Iterator<Item = &'a dyn Intersectable> {
    fn intersect(self, ray: &Ray) -> bool {
        for obj in self {
            if obj.intersect(ray) {        // Error occurs here
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let objects: [Box<dyn Intersectable>; 2] = [
        Box::new(Circle {}),
        Box::new(Circle {}),
    ];
    let ray = Ray {};

    // I wish to call intersect on the iterator as follows:
    println!("Intersection: {}", objects.iter().map(|b| b.borrow()).intersect(&ray));
}
```

This yields the error:

```
error[E0161]: cannot move a value of type dyn Intersectable: the size of dyn Intersectable cannot be statically determined
  --> src/main.rs:24:16
   |
24 |             if obj.intersect(ray) {
   |                ^^^

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*obj` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:24:16
   |
24 |             if obj.intersect(ray) {
   |                ^^^ move occurs because `*obj` has type `dyn Intersectable`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

To fix this, I tried replacing the erroneous call to `intersect` with `<T::Item>::intersect(obj, ray)` and add the following implementation ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b6a4bf1e4fb915834570d7d5b8a00d56)):

```rust
impl Intersectable for &dyn Intersectable {
    fn intersect(self, ray: &Ray) -> bool {
        (*self).intersect(ray)             // Error now occurs here
    }
}
```

I get the same error in the new code. Yet another attempt yielded `error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait` as I tried implementing it on a reference type.

---

So is it possible to implement `Intersectable` for `Iterator<Item = &dyn Intersectable>`?

Comment: Why does your `intersect` method consume the `Intersectable` (i.e. takes `self` and not `&self`)? Is it necessary for your use case?

Comment: it's just too hard to do, why make life complicated ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0fb3faf9cd6b5b4aa9f851f1717e4f64

Comment: @Cerberus I did initially have it take `&self`, but changed that so it can consume the `Iterator` without it being `Copy`. There's no reason it couldn't take `&self` for the primitives.

Comment: @Stargateur I did consider that. Ultimately, I'll be returning the closest intersection point to the ray origin, but I could still use `fold` for that. The real problem is that I want to be able to pass around the iterator as an `Intersectable` type.